# Help for electro-acoustic pickup? (Element Active System)

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, classical-guitar, pick-ups

A couple of years back I bought a classical guitar ([Admira Avila](http://www.admiraguitars.co.uk/advanced/product/63-admira-avila-guitar)), and had an acoustic pickup called the [Element Active System](http://www.lrbaggs.com/pickups/element-acoustic-guitar-pickup)  put in.

I was wondering what amps people would recommend for this pickup, and also if I would be able to plug this into a normal set of speakers. 
In the past I've managed to get the pickup working through a plain set of speakers (not sure which they were), using a 3.5mm Aux Cable and a 1/4 inch adapter. 
However, upon using the same set up with a different set of speakers (Panasonic SC-HC10), it didn't work.

I've been told in the past that this type of pickup has a preamp built in and therefore will work on normal speakers.

Any advice on how i'm supposed to use this would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a battery plugged in or some other means of powering it, then it is active.

I would not recommend plugging it into standard speakers directly as the pickup will not be line level.